# MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(System.String)'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

When I upgrade from 2.1 to 3.1 I see this error

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(System.String)'.
```

### Heading

Comment: Please share the .csproj file. Or provide a full [mre].

Comment: Not much of an upgrade. The latest MySql.Data version is [8.0.32.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/8.0.32.1), and the oldest version listed on nuget.org is [6.7.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.7.9), published over 7 years ago. Anyway, going from 3.x appears to have changed so as to be binary-incompatible with 2.x, so you'll need to modify the source code and recompile. While you're at it, switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider updating MYSQL.Data and MYSQL.EntityFramework in the Nuget Manager. This action may resolve your issue.

Ensure that the MySQL connector version you have installed matches the version of the extension you are installing in the Nuget Manager.